# Displaying Mutable PostgreSQL Arrays in the NetBeans Master/Detail Sample Form using JPA 1.0

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jpa, netbeans

**Some Background**

I have a game database with a table called Games that has multiple attributes and one called Genres. The Genres attribute is defined as an integer[] in PostgreSQL. For the sake of simplicity, I'm not using any foreign key constraints, but essentially each integer in this array is a foreign key constraint on the id attribute in the Genres table. First time working with the NetBeans Master/Detail Sample Form and Java persistence and it's been working great so far except for 1 thing. I get this error when the program tries to display a column that has a 1-dimensional integer array. In this example, the value is {1, 11}.

```
Exception Description: The object [{1,11}], of class [class org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Array], from mapping [oracle.toplink.essentials.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[genres-->final.public.games.genres]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(finalproject.Games --> [DatabaseTable(final.public.games)])], could not be converted to [class [B].
Exception [TOPLINK-3002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.ConversionException
```

**My Research**

From what I've been able to read, it looks like PostgreSQL arrays need something special done to them before you can display and edit them in this template. By default, the sample form uses TopLink Essentials (JPA 1.0) as its persistence library, but I can also use Hibernate (JPA 1.0).

Here is the code that needs to be changed in some way. From the Games.java file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "games", catalog = "final", schema = "public")
@NamedQueries({
// omitting named queries
@NamedQuery(name = "Games.findByGenres", query = "SELECT g FROM Games g WHERE g.genres = :genres")
})

public class Games implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // omitting other attributes

    @Column(name = "genres")
    private Serializable genres;

    // omitting constructors and other getters/setters

    public Serializable getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }

    public void setGenres(Serializable genres) {
        Serializable oldGenres = this.genres;
        this.genres = genres;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("genres", oldGenres, genres);
    }
} // end class Games
```

Here are also some of the sites that might have the solution that I'm just not understanding:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=946973

http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/09/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/

// omitted hyperlink due to user restriction

**Attempted Solutions**

I'm able to get the data to display if I change the type of genres to String, but it is immutable and I cannot edit it. This is what I changed to do this:

```
    @Column(name = "genres")
    private String genres;

    public String getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }

    public void setGenres(String genres) {
        String oldGenres = this.genres;
        this.genres = genres;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("genres", oldGenres, genres);
    }
```

I also attempted to create a UserType file for use with Hibernate (JPA 1.0), but had no idea what was going wrong there.

I also attempted to use the @OneToMany and other tags, but these aren't working probably because I'm not using them properly.

**What I'm Looking For**

There has to be a simple way to get this data to display and make it editable, but since I'm completely new to persistence, I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The effort put into your question shows.  Unfortunately JPA does not currently support PostgreSQL arrays.  The fundamental problem is that arrays are not frequently used in many other databases frequently and so heavy reliance on them is somewhat PostgreSQL specific.  Thus you can expect that general cross-db persistence API's are not generally going to support them well if at all.   JPA is no exception, having currently no support for PostgreSQL arrays.

I have been looking at writing my own persistence API in Java that would support arrays, but it hasn't happened yet, would be PostgreSQL-only when written, and would be based on a very different principle than JPA and friends.